# How to suppress Bootstrap 5.3.1 deprecation warning for global abs() function when compiling scss with Vite?

Tags: npm, sass, bootstrap-5, vite, deprecation-warning

I am trying to suppress a `Deprecation Warning` for `global abs() function` when compiling [`Bootstrap 5.3.1`](https://getbootstrap.com/) scss using [`Vite`](https://vitejs.dev/) with npm.

*I am using `node v16.20.2` and `npm 8.19.4` because this is the highest node version which my macOS system will let me install. However, even though I am using an outdated version of node `@16`, I am still able to use the latest npm `sass`, `vite` and `bootstrap` packages.*

See my full `package.json` config below...

```json
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "watch": "npm run dev",
    "build": "vite build",
    "production": "vite build"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "laravel-vite-plugin": "^0.8.0",
    "sass": "1.66.1",
    "vite": "^4.4.9"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.1"
  }
}
```

Here is my `vite.config.js` if anyone wants to test after installing this npm package above...

```js
import {defineConfig} from "vite";
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig(() => ({
    base: '',
    build: {
        emptyOutDir: true,
        manifest: true,
        outDir: 'build',
        assetsDir: 'assets'
    },
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            publicDirectory: 'build',
            input: [
                'resources/scss/theme.scss'
            ],
            refresh: [
                '**.php'
            ]
        })
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: [
            {
                find: /~(.+)/,
                replacement: process.cwd() + '/node_modules/$1'
            },
        ]
    }
}));
```

Here is my `theme.scss` code below, which is taken from `Option A` in [Bootstrap 5.3 Customize SASS](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/customize/sass/#importing) docs...

```scss
// Option A: Include all of Bootstrap
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

*I also get the same `Deprecated Warning` below when using `Option B` in [Bootstrap 5.3 Customize SASS](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/customize/sass/#importing) docs.*

Ok so when I compile my `theme.scss` using the npm and Vite configuration above, this is the `Deprecation Warning` outputted in the full Vite log...

```log
10:47:58 PM [vite] hmr update /resources/scss/theme.scss?direct (x8)
Deprecation Warning: Passing percentage units to the global abs() function is deprecated.
In the future, this will emit a CSS abs() function to be resolved by the browser.
To preserve current behavior: math.abs(100%)
To emit a CSS abs() now: abs(#{100%})
More info: https://sass-lang.com/d/abs-percent

   ╷
57 │   $dividend: abs($dividend);
   │              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
    node_modules/bootstrap/scss/vendor/_rfs.scss 57:14         divide()
    node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins/_grid.scss 59:12        row-cols()
    node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins/_grid.scss 85:13        @content
    node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins/_breakpoints.scss 68:5  media-breakpoint-up()
    node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins/_grid.scss 72:5         make-grid-columns()
    node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_grid.scss 38:3                @import
    node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss 20:9            @import
    resources/scss/theme.scss 2:9                              root stylesheet
```

I've tried suppressing the warning using sass variable shown below, placed at the top of my `theme.scss`, but this doesn't suppress `Deprecation Warning`...?

```scss
// Suppress Sass deprecation warning
$deprecation-warning-threshold: false;

// Option A: Include all of Bootstrap
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

I've found this related issue posted on the official Bootstrap github repo...

- https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/39028

But from what I can make out in this issue page, people are suggesting manually changing code in the `node_modules` directory...

1. In `node_modules/bootstrap/scss/vendor/_rfs.scss` file, add to top: `@use 'sass:math';`
2. In line error, replace: `$dividend: abs($dividend);` to `$dividend: math.abs($dividend);`

I would rather not do this as I am not committing the `node_modules` directory to my project repo.

Is there any other possible way to suppress this `Deprecation Warning` from my Vite log when compiling `theme.scss` with `npm run build` and `npm run dev` hot replacement module?

Any ideas would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I think you should just be patient: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/39030#issuecomment-1705970985

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not the cleanest of solutions. But until this is fixed, if I downgrade my `sass` in my npm package to version `~1.64.2` the `Deprecation Warning` does not occur.

Using the tilde `~` symbol stops this version getting updated any further when running `npm update` for other packages.

```json
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "watch": "npm run dev",
    "build": "vite build",
    "production": "vite build"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "laravel-vite-plugin": "^0.8.0",
    "sass": "~1.64.2",
    "vite": "^4.4.9"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This was fixed on September 14, 2023 https://blog.getbootstrap.com/2023/09/14/bootstrap-5-3-2/ 3 days after joshmoto's reply, so update to 5.3.2 and the warning should go away.